# Angular - Unexpected value MatDialog imported by the module AppModule

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, material-design, angular-material

I am trying to integrate Angular Material in Angular but getting following error. The program is compiled successfully but getting this issue in browser.

```
Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'MatDialog' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:485)
    at eval (compiler.js:15226)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js:15201)
    at JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.js:34385)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:34346)
    at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (compiler.js:34240)
    at CompilerImpl.compileModuleAsync (platform-browser-dynamic.js:239)
    at PlatformRef.bootstrapModule (core.js:5551)
    at eval (main.ts:11)
```

Comment: @yurzui Tried, now it gives property open does not exists on type MatDialogModule

Comment: @yurzui Tried, now it gives new error: compiler.js:485 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: 'md-dialog-content' is not a known element

Comment: @yurzui Thanks It worked

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You should import `MatDialogModule` instead.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...,
    MatDialogModule 
  ]
  ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Also don't forget that angular material has moved from `md` to `mat` in selectors.