# error TS2707 : Generic type 'MatDialogRef<T,R>' requiers between 1 and 2 arguments

Tags: angular

Please any help 
I get his error

```
 "error TS2707 : Generic type 'MatDialogRef<T,R>'  requiers between 1 and 2 arguments"
```

when I add MatDialogRef in my code
I try many solution but it doesn't work for me

```
errordialogue.ts :

import {Component, Inject, Injectable} from '@angular/core'; import {MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialog} from '@angular/material'; @Component({ selector: 'dialog-overview-example', templateUrl: 'error-dialog.component.html' }) export class ErrorDialogComponent { constructor(private dialogRef: MatDialogRef, @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data : any) { } public closeDialog(){ this.dialogRef.close(); } } 

module.ts ;I add dialogModule in the imports array 

imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, AppRouterModule, HttpModule, HttpClientModule, ReactiveFormsModule, CommonModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, MatDialog, MatDialogModule, MatDialogRef ],
```

Comment: Please include your code

Comment: import {Component, Inject, Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialog} from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'error-dialog.component.html'
})

export class ErrorDialogComponent {

  constructor(private dialogRef: MatDialogRef, @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data : any) {

  }

  public closeDialog(){
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

}
errordialogue.ts

Comment: module.ts ;I add dialogModule in the imports array                    imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRouterModule,
    HttpModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    CommonModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatDialog,
    MatDialogModule, MatDialogRef
   ],

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It errors because `MatDialogRef` needs a generic signature component class which is your `ErrorDialogComponent`

Try this

```
import {Component, Inject, Injectable} from '@angular/core'; 
import {MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialog} from '@angular/material'; 

@Component({ 
 selector: 'dialog-overview-example',
 templateUrl: 'error-dialog.component.html' 
}) 
export class ErrorDialogComponent { 
 constructor(private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ErrorDialogComponent>, @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public 
 data : any) { } 
 public closeDialog(){ this.dialogRef.close(); } 
}
```

Comment: But i get this error :   ERROR in ../../../node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/typings/aria-describer/aria-describer.d.ts(8,42): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.

Comment: try rebuilding your app

Comment: try reinstalling `@angular/material @angular/cdk` , try this `npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk`

Comment: I get this error: compiler.js:486 Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'MatDialog' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
 I try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48264880/angular-unexpected-value-matdialog-imported-by-the-module-appmodule?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Without anything other than 'It doesn't work' i can give you this answer: Follow the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the Enable Type script compiler enabled you may have same issue in the settings.